# Unable to add window — token null is not for an application from Service

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, dialog

I have an application based on RecyclerView composed of CardView, I would like to make appear an alert dialog when I click on a card view, but when I set the onClickListener, and I click on a card view, the application crashes, and I get this error: **Unable to add window — token null is not for an application from Service**.
(The same happen with a Progress Dialog).
Instead if in the onclick I set a toast I don't receive any error.
This is the code:

```
holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setTitle("Description");
                LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(context);
                TextView text=new TextView(context);
                layout.addView(text);
                builder.setView(layout);
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                AlertDialog alertDialog=builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

This is the code of the full class MyAdapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Film> listItems;
    private Context context;


    public MyAdapter(List<Film> listItems, Context context) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.view_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Film listItem = listItems.get(position);
        holder.textViewName.setText(listItem.getName());
        holder.textViewCategory.setText(listItem.getCategory());
        holder.textViewYear.setText(""+listItem.getYear());
        holder.textViewDirection.setText(listItem.getDirection());
        Picasso.with(context).load(listItem.getUrl()).into(holder.imageView);


        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setTitle("Description");
                LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(context);
                TextView text=new TextView(context);
                layout.addView(text);
                builder.setView(layout);
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                AlertDialog alertDialog=builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView textViewName;
        public TextView textViewCategory;
        public TextView textViewYear;
        public TextView textViewDirection;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public CardView cardView;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            textViewCategory = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category);
            textViewYear = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.year);
            textViewDirection=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.direction);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.playbill);
            cardView=(CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you initialize the adapter? more specifically - what `context` do you pass as an argument to its constructor?

Comment: adapter=new MyAdapter(listItems,getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
In MainActivity I inizialize adapter so.
listItems is an arrayList composed by object i want to display.

Comment: I found the solution, in the initialization I just put instead that getApplicatonContext, MainActivity.this and it worked, thanks anyway that you gave me the inspiration.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. It's a common mistake. You're welcome :)